# Max retries exceeded error when trying to save graph as png

Tags: python, altair

every time when I try to save graph as png files, I could only save for a few times and then it will be a Max retries exceeded error:

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=49307): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/90fd658175ea86931fe863c6f0bab370/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f35b033fb10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

So I cannot use altair for a long time and this will happen everytime I have some more graph to save. This is a huge problem for I need graphs saved as picture format for my further pipeline.

I run them on google colab, and this is how I install dependency to save graph as png:

```
!pip install altair_saver
!pip install selenium==4.2.0
!apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

now I have to change a runtime everytime for this error but my variables will be all lost.
Any solution to save picture as png without encountering this error? Thanks!

now I have to change a runtime everytime for this error but my variables will be all lost.
Any solution to save picture as png without encountering this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with the altair_saver methods and the next version of altair will likely use a new library called vl-convert which fixes most saving issues, but until that is released, we have to use it manually. First do `python -m pip install vl-convert-python` from your environment, then you can try this:

```
import vl_convert as vlc

def save_chart(chart, filename, scale_factor=1):
    '''
    Save an Altair chart using vl-convert
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    chart : altair.Chart
        Altair chart to save
    filename : str
        The path to save the chart to
    scale_factor: int or float
        The factor to scale the image resolution by.
        E.g. A value of `2` means two times the default resolution.
    '''
    with alt.data_transformers.enable("default"), alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows():
        if filename.split('.')[-1] == 'svg':
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write(vlc.vegalite_to_svg(chart.to_dict()))
        elif filename.split('.')[-1] == 'png':
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                f.write(vlc.vegalite_to_png(chart.to_dict(), scale=scale_factor))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only svg and png formats are supported")
```

If you wanted to use this function to save a chart as a PNG file at 2x the default resolution you would type `save_chart(my_chart, 'my-chart.png', 2)` as in this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})
my_chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)

save_chart(my_chart, 'my-chart.png', 2)
```